# HTML-CSS: item is always underlined

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the link ("55") in the top-right corner of this document is always underlined:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/print.html

I've specified text-decoration:none but it is still underlined.

**Update**:
I have an issue, I cannot add it to the  link because it is self-generated html. Also, I don't have access to the  tag of the document. Can I add a  tag in the ? Or just before the link ?

thanks

Comment: Try this: text-decoration:none !important

Comment: <span style="text-decoration:none !important;"> didn't work.. read my comments to the answer below about the other solutions... thanks

Comment: Hmmm, it's not underlined here (Chrome and Safari on Mac OS X)

Comment: i'm using safari 5.0 on MAC OS X, 55 is underlined: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/55.png

Comment: Nevermind, I was thinking italicized. So what *can* you modify? Why can't you just edit the sytlesheet?

Comment: there is not stylesheet. All css is inline and I cannot edit the <head> because I can only write in the <body>. And, the <a> tag is self-generated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to change the css style with javascript. For example:

```
   <script language="javascript">
   var objects = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

   for(var no=0;no<objects.length;no++)
   {
      objects[no].style.textDecoration = "none";
      objects[no].style.color = "#000000";
   }
  </script>
```

Comment: hi, I have an issue, I cannot add it to the <a> link because it is self-generated html. Also, I don't have access to the <head> tag of the document. Can I add a <style> tag in the <body>? Or just before the link ? thanks

Comment: If you want the code to validate properly you can't have a style block in your body only in the head. But most browsers will apply it correctly.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Denis Hoctor. Since you can't change the style with css, try to do it with javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You've put the styling on the span, you need to put your styling on the link.

Change your css from

```
span
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

to

```
span a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Or if you insist on doing it inline, put the style= on the `<a>` tag

Comment: You're on the right track, but the style is inline on the span - not in the CSS document.  Either the style needs moving to a CSS file using the selector you specified or the inline style on the span needs moving to the child link.

Comment: hi, I have an issue, I cannot add it to the <a> link because it is self-generated html. Also, I don't have access to the <head> tag of the document. Can I add a <style> tag in the <body>? Or just before the link ? thanks

Comment: Yes, I would recommend using a CSS file though, as inline styles are usually bad practice. You should read up on how to use them (it's very easy) and add some CSS as I wrote above with span a

Answer (score 0):

You can add  to body, it will work, but I'm not sure it's according to specs.
In it write
span a { text-decoration: none }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are ok to remove all underlines from all links, add this to `<head>` section of your HTML document:

```
<style type="text/css">
a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
</style>
```

BTW, compare to other solutions only mine is cross-browser compatible, `a { ... }` doesn't work on IE6.